# for and if/else loop with nested if statement not working in python

Tags: python, list, loops, nested

Below is my code to separate my lists into lists of lists, followed by printing the word 'hello' if values in these lists match... However I'm having some problems getting this to work. As far as I know, all syntax is correct, its just the output that won't work.

```
import csv
import operator
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    headers = next(csv_input)

    counter = 0
    i = 1

    for k, g in itertools.groupby(csv_input,key=operator.itemgetter(3)):
        row = []
        for entry in g:
            entry = [float(e) for e in entry]
            row.append(entry)
        counter = counter+1
        i = i+1
        #print(row)  #(not necessary to see the results hence commented out)
        if counter == 1: 
            row1 = row
        else:
            row2 = row
            for i in range(1, len(row1)):          
                hi = row1[i][0]
            for j in range(1,len(row2)):
                if row2[j][0] == hi:      #this clause doesnt work
                    print('hello')
            counter=1 
            row1=row
```

What I'm doing here is comparing the 1st value from the first list, with the 2nd value from the first line of the next list. Then, I want to compare the 1st value from first line of the second list, with the first line of the next list, and so on... (I know this seems quite confusing!), and if these values are the same, then it will plot a line, but for simplicity, lets just say it will print('hello'), as the code works up until where it is marked '#this clause doesnt work'

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: you could provide sample of the input file

Comment: You loop through all the elements of `row1` first reassigning to `hi` each time. `hi` will always be `row1[ -1 ][ 0 ]` at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then, I want to compare the 1st value from first line of the second list, with the first line of the next list, and so on...

Sounds like you want to iterate over `i` and `j` at the same time. Right now, you're iterating over `i`, then stopping, then iterating over `j`. Try using `zip`.

Replace

```
        for i in range(1, len(row1)):          
            hi = row1[i][0]
        for j in range(1,len(row2)):
            if row2[j][0] == hi:
                print('hello')
```

With

```
        for i, j in zip(range(1, len(row1)), range(1,len(row2))): 
            hi = row1[i][0]
            if row2[j][0] == hi:
                print('hello')
```

Also, not sure if this was intentional or not - starting the `range` at `1` means that you start looking at the *second* element of each list, rather than the first. Use `range(len(row1))` and `range(len(row2))` if you want to iterate over the complete lists.

Comment: thank you very much for this! that seems like a lot better way to do this. however, i'm still not getting any output other than 'runfile('/Users/name/Desktop/matrices1.py', wdir='/Users/name/Desktop')'
and that was unintentional, so thank you!

Comment: I found where I went wrong.. using your method too, if row2[j][1] == hi , instead of row2[j][0] == hi